# Permission denied while write to mounted directory

Tags: docker

Trying to start container that has mounted hosts shared folder and places file `addd.txt` there:

```
sudo docker run -it -v ~/shared:/media/ i386/centos:6 echo aaa >> /media/addd.txt
```

Got error:

```
bash: /media/addd.txt: Permission denied
```

I was trying to save file from inside of container to shared directory and it was run fine:

```
echo aaa >> /media/addd.txt
```

Why I can't create file during docker run procedure?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the redirection of output is not performed by `sudo`.

Simple workaround:

```
sudo bash -c "docker run -it -v ~/shared:/media/ i386/centos:6 echo aaa >> /media/addd.txt"
```

Comment: no file was created and no error reported after using this command

Answer (score 0):

To make the redirection work "inside" the container, you will have to use `sh -c 'your_echo_stuff_and_redirection_here'` as the container command. Something like:

- `docker run ... sh -c 'echo aaa >> /media/addd.txt'`.